# expect script freezes when called from Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, expect

I've a list of hosts on which I need to install my public key. For this purpose, I've written a ruby script that calls an expect script and passes to it my password, the host name and public key file. This expect script in turn performs ssh-copy-id to each host, by feeding in the password and answering "yes" for unknown host keys.

The expect script works absolutely fine when run for command line. But when executed from a ruby script, expect fails to answer "yes" for the unknown host key confirmation : "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?". The expect script just freezes when the yes/no question is thrown to it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my ruby script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

hosts=['test@blah1.edu','test2@blah2.edu','test3@blah3.edu']
password="blahblahblah"
key_file="/home/blah/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

hosts.each{ |host|
   command="expect sshcopy.exp #{host} #{key_file} #{password}"
  `#{command}`
}
```

And here is my expect script *sshcopy.exp* :

```
set host [lrange $argv 0 0]
set key_file [lrange $argv 1 1]
set password [lrange $argv 2 2]
spawn  ssh-copy-id -i $key_file $host
expect -nocase "*password: $" {send "$password\r"; interact}  -nocase "*are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? $" {send "yes\r"}  eof{exit}
expect -nocase "*password: $" {send "$password\r"; interact} eof{exit}
```

You will see two expect statements above. The first statement handles the case when the password is asked immediately (i.e. host key is known) by *interacting* immediately. It also handles the case when an unknown host is identified, by answering "yes".

The second expect statement is executed when the first expect answered "yes" leading to a password being asked.

Comment: In your expect script, use `lindex` with a single index instead of `lrange` with two. Otherwise you can get “surprises” if any argument contains Tcl list metacharacters (e.g., spaces or curly braces); those things are relatively likely in filenames and passwords…

Comment: Also, passing passwords on the command line is insecure. The `ps` command (with the right arguments) can read the full arguments to any process on the system. The same with environment variables (though a different option is needed to get them). The safe ways are either to send it on the stdin pipe, or to put it in a file *with strict permissions* and to pass the name of that file on the command line (because knowing the filename doesn't help a hacker read it). However, if you're on a system where you can guarantee there's no intruders (tricky!) it's not very important to be that secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the problem is that you call the expect script with `` `backticks` `` however the expect script interacts.  It seems the ruby backticks don't allow full interaction (blocking stdin perhaps). You might want to investigate ruby's expect module and do away with the separate expect script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. But I found that the answer to the problem is very simple :

```
  puts `#{command}`
```

I assumed that `` in ruby would merge the stdout and stderr handles of the shell command with the ruby script. This is wrong.